# Why does on Hover quit working after it is selected once?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>

    <head>

      <style>

        .menu{
           background-color: cornflowerblue;
         }

         .btn-group .button {
            background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
            border: 1px solid green;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 150px;
            display: block;
          }

          .btn-group .button:hover {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgb(92, 88, 46),  
                                                          rgb(247, 229, 41),              
                                                          rgb(92,88,46));
            color:red;
           }
         </style>

       </head>

       <body onload="fnOnLoad()">

         <div class="menu"> 
           <div class="btn-group">
             <button id = "WhatsNew" onclick="btnClick('WhatsNew')" class="button">What's New</button>
             <button id = "Button1" onclick="btnClick('Button1')" class="button">Button1</button>
             <button id = "Button2" onclick="btnClick('Button2')" class="button">Button2</button>
             <button id = "Button3" onclick="btnClick('Button3')" class="button">Button3</button>
             <button id = "Button4" onclick="btnClick('Button4')" class="button">Button4</button>
           </div>
         </div>

       </body>

      <script>

        let curBtn = "WhatsNew";

        function fnOnLoad(){
          /*alert("In OnLoad"); */
          btnClick("WhatsNew");
        }

        function btnClick(btnName){
          /*alert("Setting button colors.  curBtn = " + curBtn + " btnName = " + btnName);*/
          document.getElementById(curBtn).style.backgroundColor = "rgb(33, 31, 31)";
          document.getElementById(curBtn).style.backgroundImage = "none";
          document.getElementById(curBtn).style.color = "rgb(255, 234, 0)";

          document.getElementById(btnName).style.color = "rgb(17, 15, 15)";
          document.getElementById(btnName).style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgb(92, 88, 46),  rgb(247, 229, 41),  rgb(92,88,46))";
          curBtn = btnName;
          /*alert("after curBtn = " + curBtn);*/
        }

      </script>

    </body>

  </html>
```

I want the menu items to change to the gradient when hovered or when selected.  The way it's working now it works until you select that menu item.  Once you click another menu item the ones previously selected do not do the gradient anymore.

This site won't let me post without more details....  If you try the above code the first item is highlighted when it starts.  As you hover over the other items you see them highlighted.  After you select a new item the old one no longer highlights when you hover over it.  Why?

Thanks for any ideas.

Alan

Comment: Side note, you have two closing body tags

Comment: I suggest you edit your post and write this as a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set a style rule with JS you erase the one you wrote with css so it wont work anymore after being unset.

I suggest you use JS only to set class names to your element and let CSS in charge of setting the rules.

Careful to write the rules in the right order.

```js
let curBtn = "WhatsNew";

function btnClick(btnName) {
  document.getElementById(curBtn).classList.add("visited");
  document.getElementById(curBtn).classList.remove("selected");
  document.getElementById(btnName).classList.add("selected");
  curBtn = btnName;
}
```

```css
.menu {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.btn-group .button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: 1px solid green;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
}



.btn-group .button.visited {
  background-color: rgb(33, 31, 31);
  background-image: none;
  color: rgb(255, 234, 0);
}

.btn-group .button.selected {
  color: rgb(17, 15, 15);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(92, 88, 46), rgb(247, 229, 41), rgb(92, 88, 46));
}

.btn-group .button:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(92, 88, 46),
      rgb(247, 229, 41),
      rgb(92, 88, 46));
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button id="WhatsNew" onclick="btnClick('WhatsNew')" class="button">What's New</button>
    <button id="Button1" onclick="btnClick('Button1')" class="button">Button1</button>
    <button id="Button2" onclick="btnClick('Button2')" class="button">Button2</button>
    <button id="Button3" onclick="btnClick('Button3')" class="button">Button3</button>
    <button id="Button4" onclick="btnClick('Button4')" class="button">Button4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks much Peterrabbit, that was great!  I'm a C++, Delphi programmer trying to figure out this web stuff.  What did you mean when you said "Careful to write the rules in the right order."?  Also, are there any books on CSS & Javascript that you recommend?

Comment: @Alan for books I recommend Manning editions, they have a lot of things so I can't tell a book in particular but everything is very good quality https://www.manning.com/catalog/sort/sort-by-subject#section-39

Comment: @Alan and for the order of the rules I was talking about css, in here if you write the hover rule before the other ones in will be "shadowed" and wont work. This is related to css selectors hierarchy. When you have a little more advanced knowledge with css I suggest you use Sass to generate css, it's way more convenient.

Comment: Thanks again Peterrabbit.  I will look into Manning books.